# Comparison of models with transformed dependent variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, predictive-models, data-transformation, caret

I want to check if transforming the dependent variable positively influences the model performance. For example, I have built two models using the `caret` package. The first one is based on dependent variable in the original scale, and the second one used the `log1p` transformation of dependent variable.

```
library('caret')
library('ggplot2')

data(economics)

model_lasso <- train(unemploy ~ pce + pop + psavert,
                    data = economics,
                    method = "lasso")

model_lasso_log <- train(log1p(unemploy) ~ pce + pop + psavert,
                    data = economics,
                    method = "lasso")
```

The results of the models could be found below:

```
getTrainPerf(model_lasso)

 TrainRMSE TrainRsquared method
1  1641.582     0.6199305  lasso

getTrainPerf(model_lasso_log)

  TrainRMSE TrainRsquared method
1 0.2083973     0.6672033  lasso
```

Because of the transformation it is impossible to compare RMSE values. Moreover, one "cannot meaningfully compare R-squared between models that have used different transformations of the dependent variable" (http://people.duke.edu/~rnau/rsquared.htm).

Therefore, my question are: How to compare models with transformed dependent variable? Is there a way to do it using the `caret` package in R?

Comment: I have no absolute problem with comparing R-square in such cases  provided that it is done very circumspectly. The implication is that the second model predicts better in its own context than the first in _its_ own context. You have various possibilities, including whether each model is qualitatively plausible. For example, I would object to any model that predicts negative unemployment within the range of the data.  Plots of observed versus fitted and residual versus fitted can always be applied, regardless of the number of the predictors, and often flag unsuitable functional form.

Comment: How to do this in R is arguably quite off-topic here. I have focused on the underlying statistical question.

Answer (score 1):

If you transform the predicted values of `model_lasso_log` to the original scale with the inverse of `log1p`, `expm1`, then you can compare the RMSE normally, afterall you are interested in predicting values in one scale scpecifically, be it the original or the transformed one.